# SSIS 2012 Package hangs randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Intially the package was in the package deployment model (SSIS 2008), which export the data to a local CSV file in parallel from a local database.

I've converted it to Project deployment Model and now the same parallelism exists but by calling a child package (utilizing 26 threads) through Execute Package Task (earlier it was through Execute Process Task) using the Execute-Out-of-Process in-order to utilize the resources

The child package picks a random customer out of 15K customers and exports it's related data from a view to the CSV file.

**<>**
The customer are placed in a table and all the threads read the table and a mutex is applied over it using the TABLOCKX, whichever thread gets the write access first will pick-up the customer and modifies the load status to 'Progress'. The other threads waiting for the write access will follow the same process.

The process in each thread is repeated for all the customers using the "Forloop" container

For the 576 executions it exports good and quickly but surprisingly it hangs up for several minutes at the 576th execution of a random customer. I've tried to repro it for several times and it hangs up at the same point.

Your help on this is very much appreciated!!

PS: The issue is not there in the earlier version of my package

Comment: Can you explain what SSIS Tasks, SQL queries and expressions pick the random customers please. For example, is it a Loop Container with a SQL Task?

Comment: imagine you are trying to solve this,would the info provided be sufficient

Comment: Do you monitor existing connections to your SQL Server? Do you cleanly close each CSV file?

Comment: From time to time I often do experience the package hanging up and notice a additional dialog box opening in the background which usually denotes an error. Do you find any such dialog open?

Comment: Karthik.. Yes exactly at that point the package crashes

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in SSIS 2012 due to which my Migrated package Hangs.

SSIS package with multiple child packages when executed all at once creates a deadlock in the internal Catalog tables. So running a child package with multiple parallel thread should be avoid. If needed, run them with few milli seconds of delay (> 100 ms).

Adding a delay resolved the problem. Hope this bug will be resolved by Microsoft in the later versions of SSIS